# Class from one dictionary gets data from class in another dictionary by function

Tags: c#, class, dictionary, unity-game-engine

I have little problem with transforming data from one class placed in dictionary to second class, which is in another dictionary.

```
                if(GUI.Button(new Rect(Screen.width * 0.40f, Screen.height * 0.1f,Screen.width * 0.1f,Screen.height *0.1f), "Pistol")){
            ChangeWeapon (ChangedWeapon, 01);
            }
```

Heres example of button, which triggers the function.

```
    void ChangeWeapon(int ChangedWeapon, int ID){
    string WeaponSlotList[ChangedWeapon].weaponName = WeaponList[ID].weaponName;
}
```

Heres function. Changed weapon is number, meaning which slot information should be changed. ID is ID of which weapon information should be used.

```
    public class Weapon{
    public string weaponName;
    public int maxClip;
    public int spread;
    public float speed;
    public int ID;
    public Weapon(string weaponName, int maxClip, int spread, float speed, int ID){
    }
}
public Weapon Pistol = new Weapon("Pistol",15,1,0.5f,01);
public Weapon Smg = new Weapon("Smg",30,1,0.1f,01);
public Weapon AssalutRifle = new Weapon("AssalutRifle",30,1,0.2f,01);
public Weapon Shotgun = new Weapon("Shotgun",8,1,0.5f,01);
public Weapon SniperRifle = new Weapon("SniperRifle",2,1,1.0f,01);
```

Here's Weapon class constructor.

```
    public class WeaponSlot{
    public string weaponName;
    public int maxClip;
    public int spread;
    public float speed;
    public int ammo;
    public WeaponSlot(string weaponName, int maxClip, int spread, float speed, int ammo)
    {
    }
}
public WeaponSlot WeaponSlot1 = new WeaponSlot("",0,0,0.0f,0);
public WeaponSlot WeaponSlot2 = new WeaponSlot("",0,0,0.0f,0);
public WeaponSlot WeaponSlot3 = new WeaponSlot("",0,0,0.0f,0);
public WeaponSlot WeaponSlot4 = new WeaponSlot("",0,0,0.0f,0);
public WeaponSlot WeaponSlot5 = new WeaponSlot("",0,0,0.0f,0);
```

And here's the slot constructor.
Anybody have idea how the function should be written?
Also sorry for bad English, im foreign.

Comment: I have an idea for this problem. First what is the purpose of `Weapon` and `WeaponSlot`?

Comment: @FunctionR Weapon is class containing informations about specific weapon, like recoil of pistol. Weapon class informations are static, and cannot be changed. WeaponSlot is class containing informations about weapon, AND about ammo. There are 5 slots for weapon. Each have its specific and separated information. Its not static, so I can later add upgrades for weapons, but applying for WeaponSlot data.

Comment: Okay, im using now list instead of dictionares, i have errors "Argument is out of range", but ill find out why its not working myself. thanks for help, anyway.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, why are you using two different classes when they appear to be mostly identical? Both your WeaponsList and WeaponsSlotList could hold the same Weapon object, and a weapon in the WeaponsList could have ammo set to `0`.

If you follow this course, you have a couple of options. One is to just assign the value directly to `WeaponSlotList` like this:

```
void ChangeWeapon(int ChangedWeapon, int ID)
{
    string WeaponSlotList[ChangedWeapon] = WeaponList[ID];
}
```

A problem with this is that any changes made to the weapon in the `WeaponSlotList` will also be made to the one in `WeaponList`, since they are pointing to the same object. This would be problematic when dealing with ammo!

Alternatively, you can either create a new Weapon object based off the `WeaponList` object properties and assign that to `WeaponSlotList`:

```
void ChangeWeapon(int ChangedWeapon, int ID)
{
    WeaponSlotList[ChangedWeapon] = 
        new Weapon(WeaponList[ID].weaponName, WeaponList[ID].maxClip, 
            WeaponList[ID].spread, WeaponList[ID].speed, WeaponList[ID].ID);
}
```

Or just copy all the property values from the `WeaponList` weapon to `WeaponSlotList`:

```
void ChangeWeapon(int ChangedWeapon, int ID)
{
    WeaponSlotList[ChangedWeapon].weaponName = WeaponList[ID].weaponName;
    WeaponSlotList[ChangedWeapon].maxClip = WeaponList[ID].maxClip;
    WeaponSlotList[ChangedWeapon].spread = WeaponList[ID].spread;
    WeaponSlotList[ChangedWeapon].speed = WeaponList[ID].speed;
    WeaponSlotList[ChangedWeapon].ID = WeaponList[ID].ID;
}
```

Another option would be to implement a ShallowCopy method on your Weapon class, which makes it much easier for clients to get a copy of an existing weapon. Something like this:

```
public class Weapon
{
    public string weaponName;
    public int maxClip;
    public int spread;
    public float speed;
    public int ID;

    public Weapon(string weaponName, int maxClip, int spread, float speed, int ID)
    {
    }

    public Weapon GetShallowCopy()
    {
        return (Weapon) this.MemberwiseClone();
    }
}

// Calling code:
void ChangeWeapon(int ChangedWeapon, int ID)
{
    WeaponSlotList[ChangedWeapon] = WeaponList[ID].GetShallowCopy();
}
```

Another alternative, if you want to have a separate class for WeaponSlot, is to create it with a Weapon property, plus any additional properties.

```
public class WeaponSlot
{
    public Weapon weapon;
    public int ammo;
    public WeaponSlot(Weapon weapon, int ammo)
    {
    }
}
```

Or you could use inheritance, and make WeaponSlot derive from Weapon. Lots of options!!!

By the way, having 'List' as part of the name of a Dictionary object is a little confusing! You might consider having a `WeaponInventory` and `SelectedWeapons` or something like that. But that's just my opinion. :-)

Comment: Thanks, but I tried the code with copying valutes, and the ShallowCopy code, but it returns me error "The name `WeaponList' does not exist in the current context", "The name `WeaponSlotList' does not exist in the current context".

Comment: Sounds like you're missing a reference and/or using statement, or the lists have a more restrictive accessibility (i.e. private instead of public). The lists need to be accessible from the class that is trying to use them.

Comment: Well, i need to learn. Alot. `public Dictionary<int,Weapon> WeaponList = new Dictionary<Weapon>(){{1, Pistol},{2, Smg}};
public Dictionary<int,WeaponSlot> WeaponSlotList = new Dictionary<int,WeaponSlot>(){ {1, WeaponSlot1},{2, WeaponSlot2},{3, WeaponSlot3},{4, WeaponSlot4},{5, WeaponSlot5}};` Effect? https://www.dropbox.com/s/o2g7b0pd92oq3bj/prtscrn.png?dl=0 Thanks for patience, anyway.